# Kafka to Azure to Power BI

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, powerbi, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

Expected Fuctionality: send data from Kafka to azure ADLS and to power BI for visualization.

I am currently sending a hard coded text in my Kafka program (java) to Azure event hub. While Capture event hub content to ADLS gen1, .Avro file is created in ADLS. Since .avro files aren't supported in Power BI, I'm unable to proceed.

I need a solution to send the hard coded text as a .txt or .json file instead of .avro so that it ill be easy for me visualize in power BI. Else i need a solution to convert the .avro file to .txt or .json and save it in ADLS.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I don't have the comment privileges. So i will ask it here.

Can you directly create a
[image: streaming dataset in PowerBI] and [image: setup the API] with parameters and then use Kafka CURL commands to call the rest API and push data. 
I tried pushing data [image: through postman] and was able to do it. Since I haven't worked with Kafka, I can't say for sure.